# ROS Backlog Feature Request Priority Criteria

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there some formal process to support the development of Backlog Feature Requests either by voting or funding?

Thanks,

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212344/ros-backlog-feature-request-priority-criteria/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2015-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I know of. If you're serious about funding, I guess contacting the OSRF would be the first step. As for issues on the various github repositories: a `+1` with some rationale or, even better, a pull request that fixes the issue or adds the feature would be the way to get things going.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1